# How to start/stop transmission at given times?

Tags: transmission

I've checked the manual for the gtk version of Transmission (the torrent client), and haven't found a way to **stop** and **start** all transfers with a schedule. Is this just 'not supported'? or someone had found a call I can throw in cron and have my way?

I know that the servers allow RCP calls with the transmission-client, but the GTK version doesn't seems to have this option (and the [manuals](http://www.transmissionbt.com/help/gtk/) seems quite obsolete right now).

I'm using transmission-gtk 2.81.

Comment: If you are not wedded to Transmission, Deluge claims to support bandwidth scheduling but I have no experience with it. KTorrent also claims scheduling, but probably pulls in the whole KDE environment like most Kx packages.

Comment: @msw I'm going to give Deluge sometime, but for now I'm happy with Transmission. About KTorrent... I don't know... all those Klibs...

Comment: I now have 5 minutes experience with Deluge and may have a new preferred servent. It looks and behaves like more like Transmission  than anything I've seen, and its scheduler has a particularly clean interface (for each hour×weekday in a matrix you pick open, slow, or none).

Comment: fwiw you might look into the `timeout` command which can send a predefined signal a predefined number of seconds after kicking off the executable.

Comment: @JoelDavis yeah, but that close the client, and I want to keep it open if I choose to start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stopping and starting from cron, you should be able to start it if you set the DISPLAY environment variable appropriately:

```
env DISPLAY=":0.0" transmission-gtk &
```

and if you send it SIGINT it will close down the same way as if you chose Quit from its menu, properly closing connections and uploading totals to trackers:

```
killall -INT transmission-gtk
```

In "Transmission Preferences" under "Speed" there is a section "Alternative Speed Limits" that lets you set a different set of speed for a certain time. I think you could set it to 0 for both upload and download, if your only concern is bandwidth contention during some time.

Comment: I through about put 0 on Speed Limits, but the settings like "0 means no limits" throw me out the loop. Is nice. I'm not going to kill transmission right now (you know, just in case ;)) to test out. So, I'll be updating later.